# Re-create a dropped table with schema and content

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I had a table named `XXXX`. Suddenly, my table's contents were dropped (DROP table). I want to recreate my table, I know the schema of my table and I am having a text file with contents of my table before dropped.

- Can I recreate my table without insert each row because it would take
  a long time?
- Is there any easy way to transfer the contents of text file to table
  independent of the query language?

I'm using (`MSSQL`,`POSTGRESQL`,etc...)?

Comment: post file content samle?..

Comment: Use the `COPY` command to bulk-load it.

Answer (score 0):

On PotsgreSQL

Procedure will be :

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (your fields);
```

Then admit your file is with good fields separators. The default is a tab character in text format, a comma in CSV format, do :

```
COPY tablename FROM 'path-to-your-file/filename.txt' WITH DELIMITER ',';
```

The path to your file should be accessible by the PostgreSQL server to /tmp is usually the more simple way to put your file.

Then you get back your table.